# How to move image files from HDFS directory to HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera-cdh

I have Cloudera CDH 5.3.0

I have a directory in HDFS with several gigabytes of image files.

These files are of various types (jpg, png, gif).

For each file `picturename.jpg`, I want a row in HBase with `picturename` as the row key, and a column with the image data.

Can someone explain how I would accomplish something like this?

Comment: Why do you need these files to be in HBase? HBase doesn't handle large cells very well (there is even default 10Mb size limit for a cell value), serving files from HDFS might be faster than using HBase in this case.

Comment: @kostya Using Hbase relives the pressure on the NameNode, Especially when you have large number of small files.
Again, The effectiveness depends on the use case. I gather there are few folks who are using the Hbase to serve images (yfrog), but they are well tuned for thier case.
There are some developments in the Hbase to address the limitation (MOB). http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/06/inside-apache-hbases-new-support-for-mobs/

Comment: @Shyam, thats good point. One possible solution that might still work (depending on use case) is to put multiple images into a single HAR file. I agree that it all depends on use case, I just wanted to suggest the simplest way to solve the problem that still might work ;)

Comment: @kostya: Ryan didnt mention that size of Image is greater than 10 MB.

Comment: @AnilGupta, he didn't mention otherwise. Obviously this question doesn't contain enough information to recommend the best solution. I was just trying to be helpful and warned Ryan of a potential problem with HBase.

Comment: If the file is more than few MB's then there is not point of using a DB to store. Its better to store pointer to file.

Comment: @Shyam I have a usecase where I have some videos sized upto 250 MB - 300 MB, and needs Storage like HBase. Is that good or should I go for HDFS only for Storage and Fast retrieval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For background, HBase stores everything as binary. You would `Put` and `Get` binary data.
Just read Image as a BinaryFile

As you described, HBase table would look like

> rowkey `<image-name>`
>
> cf:data `<binary-image-data>`

There are several ways to ingest data into HBase.

- With or Without using mapreduce.
- Using `put` or `bulkload`.

Since you have several gigabytes of data, Fastest way would be to use a mapreduce and `bulkload`.
A useful tutorial by cloudera on bulkloads here :
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-hbase-bulk-loading-and-why/

How do you read images and supply it to hadoop?

You could do this in many ways. I'll describe methods using mapreduce, As it's more scalable.

One of the way to implement would be to write your own hadoop [`recordreader`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/RecordReader.html), which would supply binary data to the `map`.

But in your case I think we could use a shortcut, Supply a list of image path as input.
In the `map`,

```
setup(..){
  //prep FileSystem fs = ..
}

map(...) {

  String path = key.toString
  FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(new Path(val))
  //Using in.read() read as bytes. Optionally custom encoding.
  //Set the binary value to key value if using bulkload, else to the Put object.
  context.write(key, kv)

}
cleanup(..) {
 //close fs. misc.
}
```

It's a bit hacky, but I hope you get the idea.

Also read the comments. There are several design considerations to be considered if you are going to design a system based on this.

Hope it helps.